# Is it possible to return a list<string> from a webmethod and pass the return value to bind a html select using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Im trying to bind an html select and i wrote a webmethod for that, which returns a list. How can i use this return value to bind my select control using jquery.... ? I'm stuck... The code is appended herewith :

```
function columnDropdownScript() {
  var reqTableNameParameter = "Designation";  //$('#ddlTableNames').text;
  var requestTableParameters = '{' +
                        'selTableName:"' + reqTableNameParameter + '"}';
  // Configure AJAX call to server                        
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Webtop.aspx/FillColumnDropdown",
    data: requestTableParameters,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: DisplayColumnNames, //Event that'll be fired on Success
    error: DisplayError //Event that'll be fired on Error
  });

}
function DisplayColumnNames(serverResponse) {

  $("#ddlColumnNames").get(0).options.length = 0;
  $("#ddlColumnNames").get(0).options[0] = new Option("Select", "-1");
  $.each(serverResponse.d, function(index, item) {
    $("#ddlColumnNames").get(0).options[$("#ddlColumnNames").get(0).options.length] = new Option(item.Display, item.Value);
  });
  alert('Check Column DropDown');
}




 [WebMethod]
    public static List<string> FillColumnDropdown(string selTableName)
    {
        int x=1;
        string selectedTable = selTableName;
        List<string> columnsToBind = new List<string>();
        foreach (Columns column in Metadata.columnsOfSelectedTables)
        {
            if (column.TableName.Equals(selectedTable))
            {
                columnsToBind.Add(column.ColumnName);
            }
        }
       return columnsToBind;
    }
```

Comment: What exaclty is the problem? Is your ajax working and are you getting all data. Are you looking just for a way how to generate drop down list from collection of strings?

Comment: ajax is working. i mean, its hitting the we method. im returning the list from there, but dont know how to use the return value to bind a select control .

Comment: is there any property to get the length of the return value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

// I haven't tested this, but off the top of my head, this should do the trick
// (note, this is appending to the list.  you may need to clear if called multiple times)

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Webtop.aspx/FillColumnDropdown",
    data: requestTableParameters,
    //contentType: "plain/text",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        for (var i = 0, l = msg.length; i < l; i++) {
            $("#the_selectbox").append("<option>" + msg.d[i] + "</option>");
        }
    },
    error: DisplayError //Event that'll be fired on Error
  });
```

Comment: I am thinking the same. $("#the_selectbox").empty(); will clear the current contents. You will need to change the id and handle your actual json data structure, but this is the jQuery way to add to a select list.

Comment: Still not able to bind that using msg.d[i].

Comment: @Chris my alert is not even displaying the msg.d[0] if i'm hard coding it.

Comment: Start by finding out what you are getting.  At the start of the success function, can you set an alert to make sure the callback is getting triggered at all?  And then alert(msg) to see what is coming through?

Comment: Got it... Problem was with the loop shown here. it's msg.d.length, to get the length right. Thanks a lot for the help. Now the problem is with the select control. The loop is getting executed but the items are not displaying.

Comment: Good progress - your finding the strings in the loop yes? (via alert etc?).  In JQuery, you can add options to a select by $("#select_id").append('<option>Text</option>');  Obviously you'll need to change the id to match the id of your select.

Answer (score 0):

Just for curiosity, why did you do a web method for that instead of adding it onload / postback trigger?

And where are you casting your list to json in code behind? Wouldn't it's return type be xml?

Anyway, jQuery objects properties ask for anonymous functions:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    success:function(serverResponse){
        //success code
    },
    error:function(serverResponse){
        //error code
    },
});
```

Comment: I'm using this on a div pop up and  having trouble with keeping the div visibilty. That's why jumped to web method

Comment: Well, you could use the event that shows the div as trigger to populate the select